# Require a yubikey AND (publickey OR password) for SSHD auth

Tags: linux, openssh, pam, yubikey

I am attempting to configure OpenSSH on a Debian based system to *always* require a **yubikey TOTP** AND *either* a **publickey** OR **password**.

I realise other combinations are possible through `AuthenticationMethods`, but this combination does not appear to be possible with that method.

*If* `password` *were* independent of PAM, `sshd_config` would look like this:

```
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive password,keyboard-interactive
```

`/etc/pam.d/sshd` must include the Yubico PAM for SSHD to utilise it:

```
auth required pam_yubico.so id=foo key=bar
```

The above example will fail to achieve the desired combinations because password-auth *and* yubico-auth are performed through the same mechanism (PAM) defined in the same file (`pam.d/sshd`) using the same interface (`password` or `keyboard-interactive`), with the only difference being the later's capability to handle multiple user inputs via challenge-response.

For example `publickey,keyboard-interactive` results in publickey + yubikey + password and `password,keyboard-interactive` results in yubikey + password + yubikey + password - except it is not possible to satisfy due to `password`s single input limit. Disabling `common-auth` in `pam.d/sshd` will satisfy the first combination but make the second impossible.

The crux of this problem seems to be both the inability of OpenSSH `AuthenticationMethods` to separate PAM requirements from each other, and the inability of PAM to understand SSH publickey auth (which would allow the "publickey OR password" condition to be defined in PAM instead and just use `keyboard-interactive` alone in sshd).

**Is there another way to achieve this with OpenSSH and pam_yubico.so?**

Alternatively if it were possible to distinguish `password` mode from `keyboard-interactive` mode from within `pam.d/sshd` then `pam_succeed_if.so` could be used to to exclude `pam_yubico.so` or `common-auth` respectively.

Comment: Why don't you use public key with the Yubikey? This includes the best of all worlds: public key authentication, requires a secure token with a well protected private key and a password (the Yubikey PIN).

Comment: I am, i'm just also trying to allow password + yubikey for convenience when working on different machines... walking around with a private key on a usb stick + a yubikey is not secure and it's difficult to add a public key from each potential machine you are working on in advance of using it... I will unfortunately end up reverting to password+yubkey on it's own if I can't find a way for it to co-exist with optional publickeys.

Comment: The private key is on the Yubikey, no need to carry around a separate usb stick for that. The private key is secured on the Yubikey, you can't get it out of it even if you wanted to. The public key should of course be put on all servers you want to access, but that needs to be done anyway.

Comment: I'm talking about a separate private key, a normal RSA private key kept in .ssh (i know it's posisble to use GPG agent to store private keys on the yubikey but that's not what i'm doing here). The yubikey is being used for yubico TOTP through pam_yubico *not* SSH key pair through GPG agent.

Comment: Well, what I'm suggesting is the use of a normal RSA key, but stored in and operated upon on the Yubikey and the corresponding public key stored on the servers I want to access. IMO, this should be secure enough without the need to use any additional one-time password. This is what I use, without a GPG agent or any other agent.

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but from all of the examples i've looked through using yubikey for SSH RSA pair auth required some extra client configuration for a different ssh-agent... I wanted to avoid extra configuration for ssh clients for the sake of simplicity because this is to be used with multiple users, on multiple machines which would be inconvenient... is there a way to avoid client configuration and use RSA key pair?

Comment: Opensc or some other PKCS#11 software is needed for the ssh client to communicate with the Yubikey. [This link](https://developers.yubico.com/PIV/Guides/SSH_with_PIV_and_PKCS11.html) has some information.